# JS validation of textarea integrated with SCEditor

Tags: javascript, validation, textarea

my JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sky94132003/083u7y9g/

I used SCEditor for a form textarea.

I want to simple validation empty.

**just a alert is ok.**

But Why I can't validation the SCEditor ???

if normal textarea will be ok?

this my js code.  my js skill not good.

```
//validation
    function check(form) {
        var Message = form["message_content"];
        if (test(Message) === false) {
            alert("content??");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function test(textarea) {
        var val = textarea.value;
        if (val == "" || !val) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

how can I normal check the textarea if not null > true?

I think maybe I can validation 
$('textarea').sceditor('instance')
????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that problem.

The sceditor author answer me.

using this API to get data

```
 var val = $('#message_content').sceditor('instance').val();
```

So, I fixed that problem in this demo

If you need that , you may go to the test on here

http://jsfiddle.net/sky94132003/083u7y9g/4/